# In Python is it possible to extract and re-use the types of variadic collections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variadic-functions, mypy, python-typing

Is it possible to modify `deco_with_params` in the following snippet to accept an arbitrary number of sequences of generic types while keeping it fully type hinted?

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping, Callable, Sequence
import functools

def deco_with_params(arg1: Sequence[int], arg2: Sequence[str]) -> Callable[[Callable[[int, str], None]], None]:
    def decorator(afunc: Callable[[int, str], None]) -> None:
        afunc(arg1[0], arg2[0])  # just a shortcut for what would be a permutation
    return decorator

@deco_with_params(arg1=[1, 2, 3], arg2=["one", "two", "three"])
def foo(arg1: int, arg2: str) -> None:
    print(arg1, arg2)
```

I.e. I don't want to be limited to two arguments (which could be accomplished by just `TypeVar`s instead of `int` and `str`, but I also have to access the type of the sequences because I want to use them one by one.

So

```py
@deco_with_params(string=["one", "two", "three"], number=[4., 5.1, 6.7], extra=[True, False])
def foo(string: str, number: float, extra: bool) -> None:
    print(string, number, extra)
```

should be accepted by `mypy`, while

```py
@deco_with_params(string=["one", "two", "three"], number=[True, False], extra=[4., 5.1, 6.7])
def foo(string: str, number: float, extra: bool) -> None:
    print(string, number, extra)
```

should not (because here `extra` would be `float` instead of `str` and thus not matching the signature anymore)

I've read about [`TypeVarTuple`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) but I didn't manage to wrap my mind enough around the provided examples to be able to tell if it's possible to extract types out of variadic *collections* this way..

Comment: There's no way to express `*args: [SomeType[_T] for _T in _Ts]`, where `_Ts` is a `TypeVarTuple`. If you insist on strict checking, write 5-6 overloads for 0..5 arguments and a fallback with `*args: Sequence[Any]`. If it's not a public API for real external usage - consider just dropping this check and using `*args: Sequence[Any]` only.

Comment: Your "should not" won't work, because you've passed them as keyword arguments (`string=...`, `extra=...`). Keyword arguments can be passed in any order. You'll have to pass it as positional arguments like `@deco_with_params(["one", "two", "three"], [True, False], [4., 5.1, 6.7])` for it to trigger a type-checking error.

Comment: Ok, my negative-example was quite wrong and misleading - instead of exchanging the values with their types I swapped the whole key-value pair and typing would have been fine of course. Thanks for the hint! @STerliakov - I'm not sure if I understand your comment. Is the `.. for _T in _Ts]` meant to keep the order? Or does my now corrected should-not-work-example somehow change the game now?

Answer (score 1):

At first I wasn't completely sure this was possible, but with a little reworking and some quite new decorator syntax it's doable. To do this I've said we invoke a new call of the decorator for each attribute in the function. With each call it addresses the next attribute in line, reducing the function to the point it takes 0 args. On execution it then prints a line for each permutation:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Concatenate, Sequence, TypeVar, ParamSpec


T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")
def deco_with_params(deco_arg: Sequence[T]):
    def outer(f: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], None]) -> Callable[P, None]:
        def new_func(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
            for x in deco_arg:
                f(x, *args, **kwargs)
        return new_func
    return outer

@deco_with_params([True, False])
@deco_with_params([4., 5.1, 6.7])
@deco_with_params([1, 2, 3])
def foo(arg1: int, arg2: float, arg3: bool) -> None:
    print(arg1, arg2, arg3)

foo()
```

This ensures the types in each list match the function signature in the way you intended - hope this is useful!